# Wordpress ModRewrite does not work?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tested this rule on a non-WP-Domain, and it works perfeclty:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^dsgvo_gdpr/(.+)$ dsgvo_gdpr/?mail=%1
```

I need simply rewrite the querystring-parameter "m" to be "mail", because "m" is a reserved word in wp -.-

but as soon as I place the rule in the .htaccess of WP, it does not work. I have read now, that WP has its own rewrite-system, but whatever I try, it does not work.

Can someone help me to achieve this please? I am dealing with this for weeks now :/

Comment: WordPress usually has its own clean URLs method which you can change through the settings. If you wanted to do it through `.htaccess` you would have to disable the option that allows you to do it through WordPress.

Comment: Need more info. Why can't you change the incoming URLs? why does the incoming path have a part after `dsgvo_gdpr` which gets removed from the rewritten URL? Why are you testing the entire query string?